# NHibernate TransactionService implemenation example

Tags: nhibernate, session, fluent-nhibernate, transactions, lazy-loading

I keep getting the following message while retrieving my domain objects:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role no session or session was closed
```

I know the problem has something to do with lazy loading of the collection on my domain object and i'm trying to fix this, but it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction. The problem is that i have a using statement on my session object and i would like to get rid of the sessions in my repository classes.

Stefan Steinegger recommended to use a TransactionService wich manages the transactions in the following post:

- [C# Shared Transactions and NHibernate using IRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026994)

It would be nice someone can provide a tutorial, example on how to implement such a service.

Comment: what type of application is this - a web application, windows forms, wpf, silverlight, etc?

Comment: it's a asp.net mvc3 webapplication

Comment: Are you also using any kind of Inversion of Control/Dependency Injection Container?

Comment: yes, i'm using Ninject inside my project...

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different ways that you can handle this within a web application and *probably* the most common in web applications is a Session Per Web Request.

Inside of `Application_Start` in `global.asax.cs`, create the SessionFactory and assign it to a static property:

```
public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // your configuration setup
    var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure();
    SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Then, in `Application_BeginRequest` in `global.asax.cs`, open a session using the SessionFactory and bind it to the `CurrentSessionContext`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
}
```

and in `Application_EndRequest` in `global.asax.cs`, unbind the session and dispose of it

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    session.Dispose();
}
```

Now inside of the application, whenever a session is required, we simply ask the `SessionFactory` for the current session

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products = null;
        var session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // your query, which sounds like it should also eager load
            // a child collection
            products = session.QueryOver<Product>().List();
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return View(products);
    }
}
```

There are numerous variations on this, including using a [`LazySessionContext`](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx) to lazily create a session only if one is needed for a request, and implementations where `ISessionFactory` could be injected into you controllers through dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I think this can help me in the right direction. I will give it a try and post my findings...

Comment: @Russ Cam :  by the way `Application_Start` is fired every asp-net-application creation, so it's fired multiple times over an application lifetime, if needed, (by default, 5 for every core if I can remember well). Of course you will overwrite the previous static instance in a not thread-safe way.

Comment: I have tried your example and it works like a charm! This project will never be used in production, it's just for study purposes. I will receive my NHibernate in Action book this week, so i can learn some more about this, my first impression is very good :-)

Comment: @MicheleLepri - do you have any more details / links to articles on when application instances are created? I know the usual cases (App Pool recycles, application restarted, etc) but I'd like to know more about other niche/edge situations when instances might be created

Comment: @Russ Cam - to understand how it works, you can log the `Application_Start` calls.
Each `"HttpApplication"` is created when the others are busy.
From a point of view, is like to have another application instance for your web-server.
Of course the cache is shared, for example.
Here is a link about the architecture
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx) and a SO question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394041/asp-net-httpapplication-lifecycle)